# Website design has a lot of images and is increasing load time

Tags: html, css, image

I work for a company that's going through a website redesign, and the designers have sent me a PSD file with mockups of the static pages. This is a typical parallax scrolling type deal that seems to be all the rage right now, and there are some large images in the mockup that will end up on the site.

I've chopped out the relevant graphics from the PSD and saved them with JPG where I don't need transparency, however I'm forced to use PNG when I do and some of these images are pushing 500kb in size resulting in the page size totaling about 3 megabytes, and I'm not even done! This is also being saved with Photoshop's "Save for Web" feature.

Considering over half our traffic comes from mobile devices, this is a big problem. What are some good techniques to cut down on the size of these images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first step should be to go back to the designers, tell them the design is too heavyweight and work with them to find a way to load fewer, lighter images.

Tools like [PNGGauntlet](http://pnggauntlet.com/) and [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/) can help reduce the size of PNGs (and JPGs). They tend to get a better (smaller) result than just Save for Web alone.

[Lazy loading images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=lazy%20load%20image%20on%20scroll) so they only get downloaded when they scroll into view is another technique to look into. Where possible, use built-in CSS tools such as [gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_gradients), [shadows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow), and the like. Maybe a vector format like SVG can be used for some of the images?

And, as [Kobus Myburgh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19975950/13019) hinted, you can use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to load smaller background images on smaller screens. If they're all background images, you might be able to get away with stretching smaller ones (using CSS `background-size`) on larger screens. Foreground images are trickier, but something like picturefill or a `srcset` polyfill might do the trick.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. I'm running all the site's images through PNGGauntlet now with decent results. I'll probably implement lazy loading as well.

Comment: https://github.com/BBC-News/Imager.js/ might be worth a look. It's a combination responsive images + lazy load script by the guys at BBC News.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is "responsive images". Read more here for techniques to solve:

https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

This is but one example of responsive images. There are many out there. Try Googling the term.

Comment: How come responsive images decrease the size of the images? AFAIK, they just shrink the original image..

Comment: Well, the solution is to have multiple images for multiple screen sizes/devices, so if the images are smaller in width * height, obviously, their file size should be smaller. The device will then load the correct sized picture for the device it is meant to. So - while most responsive images solutions will not solve the large image size problem for ALL devices (as the original image is still used on some devices), it will solve a lot of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try some lossless compression techniques .

Reference : 
[Lossless compression of images](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/)